# "v1.copy" could not be called as a function

Tags: javascript, oop, processing, p5.js

I've been following one of Daniel Shiffman's tutorials for steering behaviors(seeking) and based on the tutorial, I created a class that contains two objects (vehicle, target) and then I added them to the main sketch; right now I'm getting this error which addressed a strange line that doesn't even exist.

[p5js web editor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gALCM.jpg)

I tested the same code with vs code and chrome, but still, chrome's console showed the same error but yet with another reference to an odd line.

the main purpose of this code is that vehicle must seek the target.

this is the main sketch :

```
let vehicle;
let target;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  vehicle = new Vehicle(50, 50);
  target = new Target(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  let steering = vehicle.seek(target);
  vehicle.applyForce(steering);

  vehicle.show();
  vehicle.update();
  
  target.show();
  target.update();
}
```

and this is the vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.vel = createVector(0, 0);
    this.acc = createVector(0, 0);
    this.maxSpeed = 4;
    this.maxForce = 1;
    this.r = 16;
  }

  seek(target) {
    let force = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.pos);
    force.setMag(this.maxSpeed);
    force.sub(this.vel);
    force.limit(this.maxForce);
    return force;
  }

  applyForce(force) {
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  update() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.set(0, 0);
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    rotate(this.vel.heading());
    triangle(-this.r, -this.r / 2, -this.r, this.r / 2, this.r, 0);
    pop();
  }
}

class Target extends Vehicle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(200, 0, 0);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pox.y, this.r);
  }
}
```

Comment: The error lacks a stack trace, so it's hard to say what line is causing it.
Try executing the code in a local environment, or put a link to the web editor if that editor allows it

Comment: By the way, at a first glance, your code looks correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to like it, but it's typos :)

- `this.pos.y`, not `this.pox.y` on line 71
- `let force = p5.Vector.sub(target.pos, this.pos);` (not `let force = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.pos);` on line 36

Your code runs just fine otherwise:

```js
let vehicle;
let target;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  vehicle = new Vehicle(50, 50);
  target = new Target(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  target.pos.set(mouseX, mouseY);
  vehicle.applyForce(vehicle.seek(target));

  vehicle.show();
  vehicle.update();
  
  target.show();
  target.update();
}

class Vehicle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.vel = createVector(0, 0);
    this.acc = createVector(0, 0);
    this.maxSpeed = 4;
    this.maxForce = 1;
    this.r = 16;
  }

  seek(target) {
    let force = p5.Vector.sub(target.pos, this.pos);
    force.setMag(this.maxSpeed);
    force.sub(this.vel);
    force.limit(this.maxForce);
    return force;
  }

  applyForce(force) {
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  update() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.set(0, 0);
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    push();
    translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    rotate(this.vel.heading());
    triangle(-this.r, -this.r / 2, -this.r, this.r / 2, this.r, 0);
    pop();
  }
}

class Target extends Vehicle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(200, 0, 0);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've noticed you've changed 2 more things in the main sketch and the seek function. for the force variable, I thought that I should subtract the whole target vector from the position of the vehicle to create a vector that points to the target, but in your code, you've decided to subtract only the position of the target (target.pos) from the position of the vehicle, I wonder why it's not worked with my code; and in the main sketch, although I set the position of the target on (mouseX, mouseY) in the function setup, you've set the target position on the mouse in the draw function too. thank you!

Comment: Nice that you picked that up, forgot to add that to the answer. Yes, you can subtract the whole target vector, however, `target` itself is a `Vehicle` and it **has** a vector (uses composition) (`loc` in this case). `target` is not a `p5.Vector` itself (doesn't extend this class) so it can be subtracted directly from another vector. Yes, also you only set the mouse position to the target once in `setup()` instead of continuously in `draw()` which is what you meant likely.